# Doubt with this serie of function defined by parts.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

i need find the point limit of this function, of course, if the limit exists.
Determine the point limit of $\left\{ f_{n}\right\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x\leq n\\
x-n & x\geq n
\end{cases}$

Then...

$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x\leq\infty\\
\infty & x\geq\infty
\end{cases}$

Is right this?

I have a problem with $x\leq\infty$ and $x\geq\infty$ i think that is bad, can someone help?

Comment: Which real numbers $x$ satisfy $x\geq\infty$?

Comment: I don't know @MatthewLeingang For that im question this problem...

Answer (score 0):

A pointless limit means that you take a fixed $x$ and see what happens with $f_n(x)$ as $n$ grows to infinity.

Now, whatever $x$ we take, at some point $n$ will become greater than it, so $f_n(x)$ would irreversibly become $0$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we consider the usual order relation
\begin{align*}
-\infty<x<\infty
\end{align*}
So, the expression $x\geq \infty$ is not correct.

> We instead fix an arbitrary real number $x$. We recall the limit of a sequence does not change, when changing $finitely$ many elements of the sequence and we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{{n\to\infty}\atop{n>x}}f_n(x)=0
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0\qquad\qquad \text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}
> \end{align*}